# Strange evaluation of Bessel Functions near $x=730$?

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I am doing a calculation which involves the numerical evaluation of the following function:

$$f(x)=I_0(x)K_0(x)-I_1(x)K_1(x)$$

where $I_{\nu}(x)$ and $K_{\nu}(x)$ are the modified Bessel functions. By the asymptotic expansion quoted in [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40), I expect the following leading-order asymptotic expansion:

$$\left.f(x)\right._{x\rightarrow\infty}\sim \frac{1}{4x^3}$$

However when I plot this function, I get strange sporadic behavior around $x\in(725,742)$. As far as I can tell, I get no such error anywhere else. This is almost certainly numerical error.

[image]

**Question(s):** What exactly is this? Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: In version 11, I am unable to reproduce the plot you gave, even tho what Bill said about subtractive cancellation is correct.

Comment: I'm using version 12.0. Are you saying that you have no errors, even without manually changing the working precision?

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baycK.png) is a screenshot from the computer I am currently borrowing. Now that I have tried the version in the cloud, I can see that the disastrous subtractive cancellation is now at play.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare

```
Plot[BesselI[0,x]BesselK[0,x]-BesselI[1,x]BesselK[1,x],{x,725,742}]
```

versus

```
Plot[BesselI[0,x]BesselK[0,x]-BesselI[1,x]BesselK[1,x],{x,725,742},WorkingPrecision->64]
```

If you are curious about why this might be happening then you could inspect

```
Table[{BesselI[0,x],BesselK[0,x],BesselI[1,x],BesselK[1,x]},{x,725.,742.}]
```

and see the magnitudes of numbers that you are subtracting and getting results near 10^-9 when you have only a handful of digits using the default `MachinePrecision`.